# Uncaught Error, Syntax Error, unrecognized expression [JQUERY]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this view:

```
<select class="form-control" id="cust_name" name="cust_name">
        <option value="" class="adr" role=""> </option>
        <?php foreach ($groups as $each) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $each->cust_name; ?>" class="adr<?php echo $each->cust_name; ?>" role="<?php echo $each->cust_address; ?>"><?php echo $each->cust_name; ?></option>';                         
        <?php } ?>
        </select>

<div>                    
<textarea id="address" name="address"></textarea>
</div>
```

and here my js:

```
<script>
   $('#cust_name').change(function(){        
   var m = (this.value);
   var n = $('.adr' + m).attr('role');
   $('#address').val(n);
   return false;
   });
</script>
```

I want to show the address based on Customer name selection on combo box, it all works fine on my localhost, but when I put it into Live server it always return this error when I change the select value:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .adrFAJAR
>   SEPTIAN, BPK.
>
> at Function.ga.error (jquery.js:2)
>
> at ga.tokenize (jquery.js:2)
>
> at ga.select (jquery.js:2)
>
> at Function.ga [as find] (jquery.js:2)
>
> at r.fn.init.find (jquery.js:2)
>
> at new r.fn.init (jquery.js:2)
>
> at r (jquery.js:2)
>
> at HTMLSelectElement. (dashboard:253)
>
> at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery.js:3)
>
> at HTMLSelectElement.q.handle (jquery.js:3)

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thank you

Comment: well it is not a valid selector. It is saying you are doing this: `$(".adrFAJAR SEPTIAN, BPK.")`

Comment: well the FAJAR SEPTIAN is the value from class="adr<?php echo $each->cust_name; ?>"
so how the valid selector would be? @epascarello

Comment: class shouldn't have space in it i think.

Comment: Why are you even doing that? You have the select element, you know what is selected, read the attribute from the option.

Comment: @LongKim ah you are right, I try with the one that have no space and it showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is wrong because that is not how you generate a selector to look at a value. There is no reason to even do that. Just get the selected option.

```
var role = $("#cust_name option:selected").attr('role');
```

or

```
var role = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('role');
```